# GODOT: Positioning 3D Object at Screen Edge

Tags: godot, gdscript

I want to place a plane mesh at the left edge of the screen. How do I calculate the position and set it using GDScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current `Camera` with `get_viewport().get_camera()`.

And you can ask a `Camera` for its viewing volume with `get_frustum()`, which returns an array with the planes, in the following order: near, far, left, top, right, bottom.

Now, you say left *edge*… That would be the segment from the near-left-top intersection to the near-left-bottom intersection. So we use the `intersect_3` method of the `Plane` class.

At viola:

```
var camera := viewport.get_camera()
var planes := camera.get_frustum() 
var near_plane := planes[0]
var left_plane := planes[2]
var top_plane := planes[3]
var bottom_plane := planes[5]

var near_left_top := near_plane.intersect_3(left_plane, top_plane)
var near_left_bottom := near_plane.intersect_3(left_plane, bottom_plane)
```

There `near_left_top` and `near_left_bottom` would be `Vector3`, in global coordinates, that represent the left edge of the screen in space.

---

By the way you can ask a `Plane` for its normal, for example:

```
var left_normal := left_plane.normal
```

We can use that to build a `Basis`. Something like this (this might not be the way you want to arrange the axis):

```
var axis_y := (near_left_bottom - near_left_top).normalized()
var axis_z := left_normal
var axis_x := axis_y.cross(axis_z)
var basis := Basis(axis_x, axis_y, axis_z)
```

And then you just need a position to make a transform. For example (this might not be the position you want):

```
var origin := (near_left_bottom + near_left_top) * 0.5
var plane_transform := Transform(basis, origin)
```

And then set it as the `global_transform` of your `MeshInstance` or whatever.

---

I doubt this is exactly how you want it, but I hope I have given you enough information to adapt it to your needs.

*By the way, I'll remind you that the simplest way to have something follow the `Camera` is to make it a child of the `Camera`.*

Comment: Thank you @Theraot for such an elaborate answer. I could get the 3d position by calling camera.project_position. However I am not quite sure what the second parameter to the call z_depth signify. For me a value of 10 works after trial and error.

Comment: @LomaHarshana `z_depth` is depth of the screen space, you can think of it as distance from the camera.